# Java SingleTable inheritance in db structure using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, single-table-inheritance

I have models/Entities as follow:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Insurance extends Generic<Insurance> {
    @OneToOne public myInsurance.models.liability.hivAndVHProtection.Hiv_Answer hivAndVHProtectionAnswer;
}


@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Answer extends Generic<Answer> {}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class Hiv_Answer extends Answer {
    @OneToOne public HivAndVHProtection_Variant variant;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
public class Hiv_AnswerForEntities extends Hiv_Answer {
    public int proffesionGroup;
    public int personCount;
    public int contributionPerPerson;
    @Transient public int totalContribution;
}
```

I would like to have in db two tables:
`Insurance` and `Hiv_Answer`

I would like that Entities: `Hiv_Answer` and `Hiv_AnswerForEntities` be persisted in table `Hiv_Answer` (share common ID pool)

I would like to have in table `Insurance` relation to table `Hiv_Answer` f.e. in column `Hiv_Answer_id`

I've tried a lot of combination with annotation. None worked like it supose.

Current configuration for me seems to be OK, but it isn't. I am getting extra table: `Hiv_AnswerForEntities`, and I don't have relation to `Hiv_Answer` table at all.

It seems that instead use `strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` from `Hiv_Answer` Entity it use `strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` from superclass `Answer`

I can't find my mistake.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: May be you need @Inheritance on the Hiv_AnswerForEntities table?

Comment: I've added that annotation to `Hiv_AnswerForEntities` Entity, but nothing had change. Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPA you can't redefine your inheritance strategy down the inheritance tree, the root definition of the inheritance sets it for the whole inheritance tree

Comment: Such a shame. Is it possible in any other Persistence Framework You know? Any chance they will consider this in specification?

Comment: The JDO persistence API has allowed that for years.